# Probabilistic distribution with Python

Tags: python, math, probability, weibull

I woule like to generate samples for testing according to various type of continuous probability distribution function (PDF). For example, I have a PDF over 24 hours, and I would like to know the probability of an event to happen at 10 min, at 20 min, at 30 min .... and so on.

Hence, I would like to compute P(a < X < a + n), where n is a time value of my choice. Does it exists any module capable of doing this with Python ? Is it also usable for summation of PDF ?

Here is one figure of what I would like to achieve
[image]

I would like to retrieve the red histogram, using the blue PDF. I have been able to do it here as I already know the number of event at each time slice, but I would like to do it automatically. Here it is a Weibull function but it could be anything else (mostly normal and weibull).

Is there something that could help me in python ?

Thanks.

edit: The code for CDF and PDF of Weibull:

```
def weibull_pdf(scale, shape, x):
    """
    Determine the probability P(x ).
    :param scale: Scale parameter of Weibull distribution.
    :param shape: Shape parameter of Weibull distribution.
    :param x: Value.
    :return: Value of f(x).
    """
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    return (shape / scale) * ((x / scale) ** (shape - 1)) * np.exp(- (x / scale) ** shape)

def weibull_cdf(scale, shape, x):
    """
    Determine the cumulative distributive function for the Weibull distribution.
    :param scale: Scale parameter of Weibull distribution.
    :param shape: Shape parameter of Weibull distribution.
    :param x: Upper bound of the distribution.
    :return: P(x <= X).
    """
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    return 1 - np.exp(- (x / scale) ** shape)
```

The PDF is determined like this:

```
# Determination of the PDF function.
for i in range(1, 10):
    cdf = weibull_cdf(SCALE, SHAPE, i) - weibull_cdf(SCALE, SHAPE, i - 1)
    print"CDF for interval [{}, {}]: {}".format(i - 1, i, str(cdf))
x = [i / (INPUTS_NB / 10.0) for i in range(INPUTS_NB)]
results = [weibull_pdf(SCALE, SHAPE, x[j]) for j in range(len(x))]
```

edit2: Ok so I didn't really notice this when I was coding but I have already answer my own question in the upper batch of code (Determination of the PDF function). However, thanks DYZ for the information. Just need to do P(X < a+n) - P(X < a) to determine P(a < X < a+n)..

Comment: How is the PDF given to you? Is it a Python function?

Comment: For the above function, I already have the parameters and just coded the law. Else, I am using my EM tool on the samples to retrieve the law parameters and use them with functions I have developed.

Comment: But have you read my question? Please include the definition of the PDF function, in Python, in your question.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: First, there is a ready implementation of Weibull PDF in `numpy.random.weibull()`. You may want to use it for efficiency, as it can generate tons of samples at once, and that's what you need: create array `arr` of many samples (10,000?) and call `numpy.histogram(arr)`.

Comment: Ok I will check this so. Thanks for the info, will do some test on this.